# VSCode .editorconfig cannot apply settings to C# code

Tags: javascript, c#, typescript, visual-studio-code, editorconfig

I am trying to apply some settings e.g. `trim_trailing_whitespace` for `C#` code as well as `js` part in VSCode by using the following settings:

```
# Editor configuration, see https://editorconfig.org
root = true

[*]
charset = utf-8
trim_trailing_whitespace = true; // it is working for TypeScript and JavaScript, not C#

[*.md]
max_line_length = off
trim_trailing_whitespace = true

[*.cs]
trim_trailing_whitespace = true; // I add this to make it work for C#
```

But it does not work for C# code. Is it not possible to make it work in C#? I just try to test it for `trim_trailing_whitespace` but not working for C# while working  TypeScript and JavaScript. Here is some info related to that:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change
trim_trailing_whitespace for C # to
this "files.trimTrailingWhitespace"

and Make sure you are working on these steps:

Open Visual Studio Code User Settings (menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Settings* → *User Settings* tab).

Click the  icon in the top-right part of the window. This will open a document.

Add a new `"files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true` setting to the User Settings document if it's not already there. This is so you aren't editing the Default Setting directly, but instead adding to it.

Save the User Settings file.

ref:
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.trimtrailingwhitespace?view=visualstudiosdk-2019

Comment: Perfecto!.. But in this case I think .editorconfig settings cannot be applied to C# code? Is that true? I would expect I make the same settings on .editorconfig as I do for Javascript, Typescript, etc. files. Any idea?

Comment: On the other hand, I cannot vote up you, could you pls vote up my question so that I can get enoug repo for vote up?